# How to connect PhpSpreadsheet with production?

Tags: git, phpspreadsheet

Current repository of PhpSpreadsheet is repository for developers.

- It has bin/ with developer tools
- It has docs/ for users-developers
- It has samples/ for user-developers
- It has tests/ with developer tests
- It has phpunit and other developer config files

For production I need only content of src/ plus few psr-libraries (36MB vs 3.6MB).  And I need to has connection with your repository for possibility to update PhpSpreadsheet in any time.

How can I do this?

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you describe what the problem in my question? You links more about bug reports. But I have the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While no one can answer, I found not bad solution:

We can create in required directory ".bin/" (dot - to hide from web).
And put in it 2 files:

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "dev-develop"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://github.com/your_username/PhpSpreadsheet"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "../"
    }
}
```

setup.bat (for Windows):

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0

echo - Getting the library -
call composer.bat install
echo - done -

echo.
echo - Remove developer files -
:: library files
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\.git
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\.github
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\bin
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\docs
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\samples
rmdir /s /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\tests
del /f /q ..\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\CHANGELOG.PHPExcel.md

:: sub-library files

:: composer files
del /f /q /s ..\psr\composer.*
del /f /q /s ..\phpoffice\composer.*

:: global files files
del /f /q /s ..\README.md
del /f /q /s ..\CONTRIBUTING.md
del /f /q /s ..\phpcs.xml
del /f /q /s ..\*.dist
del /f /q /s ..\*.yml
del /f /q /s ..\*.sh
del /f /q /s ..\.git*
echo - done -

pause
```

Own repository for possible not popular fixes. But if not required, can be used official repository.

setup.bat can use for install/update.

For linux we need similar to setup.bat shell file.